# Merging two lines in a text file if they start with the same expression

Tags: linux, shell

I have one file that looks like this

```
>Unc14086 
AGAGUUUGAU 
>Unc35443
GCACGAGAAA
```

So, every n (n may vary) lines the next line starts with ">", that is the beginning of a new block of information.

I have another tab-delimited file:

```
Unc14806 InformationalTextExample
Unc35433 InformationalTextExampleII
```

My goal is to parse the second file with information found in lines starting with ">" in the first file. Whenever a matching pair occurs, i want to write "InformationalTextExample" in that line, possibly separated by "_":

```
>Unc14086_InformationalTextExample
AGAGUUUGAU 
>Unc35443_InformationalTextExampleII
GCACGAGAAA
```

How would that be possible?

Thank you!

Comment: tell me it is a typo `>Unc14086 ` or `Unc14806 Inf...`

Comment: A table processor (MS Excel or OOCalc/LOCalc) will probably do you wonders with this one.

Comment: Sorry, i have corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to provide an input/output example to help people to understand your question and problem. but please try to avoid typoes!!!

Look at your example:

```
>Unc14086  then Unc14806 Inf...
      ^              ^
>Unc35443  then Unf35433 Inf...
   ^              ^
```

Anyway, this one-liner will help you:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1"_"$2;next}sub(/^>/,"",$1){$0=">"a[$1]}7' FS="\t" f2 f1
```

`f2` is the file without `>`

example with fixed typo:

```
kent$  head f2 f
==> f2 <==
Unc14086        InformationalTextExample
Unc35443        InformationalTextExampleII

==> f <==
>Unc14086
AGAGUUUGAU 
>Unc35443
GCACGAGAAA

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1"_"$2;next}sub(/^>/,"",$1){$0=">"a[$1]}7' FS="\t" f2 f
>Unc14086_InformationalTextExample
AGAGUUUGAU 
>Unc35443_InformationalTextExampleII
GCACGAGAAA
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Perl for the task. I assumed the files are named `1.fasta` and `1.tsv`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %name_of_id;
open my $TSV, '<', '1.tsv' or die $!;
while (<$TSV>) {
    my ($id, $name) = split /\t/;
    $name_of_id{$id} = $name;
}
close $TSV;

open my $FASTA, '<', '1.fasta' or die $!;
while (<$FASTA>) {
    if (my ($id) = /^>(\S*)/) {
        if (exists $name_of_id{$id}) {
            chomp;
            print $id, '_', $name_of_id{$id};
        } else {
            warn "WARNING: $id not found!\n";
            print;
        }
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with perl, so i accepted the shell-based solution. Thank you very much for your effort anyway.